# Vacuuming database termination for postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was doing database vacuuming to free up disk space for `postgreSQL` database. The corresponding table size was large and it was taking long time for vacuuming to get complete. But unfortunately because of slow network connection , the network connection got terminated which resulted vacuuming getting terminated in middle.

I am worried whether any database corruption will occur. Can I once again issue database vacuum command?

`vacuum full message_log`;

Please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am worried whether any database corruption will occur

No database corruption will occur due to an interrupted `VACUUM`, whether it was whole-database or just one table, and whether it was a an ordinary `VACUUM` or a `VACUUM FULL`. `VACUUM` is completely safe to abort at any time. At worst it'll leave some extra table and index bloat that a later `VACUUM` run (that completes) will clean up.

In fact, it's also crash-safe so long as the underlying storage subsystem respects `fsync()`, which is a basic requirement for PostgreSQL reliability. It wouldn't even matter if PostgreSQL crashed, or if the machine was reset suddenly. In that case PostgreSQL would just recover from transaction logs.

Answer (score 4):

I found this post from the pgsql-admin mailing list that claims it can safely be started again: 
[Re: Partial/interrupted VACUUM FULL?](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12786.1067289440@sss.pgh.pa.us)

The full text of this post is as follows:

```
Jeff Boes <jboes(at)nexcerpt(dot)com> writes:
> Can I do a VACUUM FULL for a while, and interrupt it (CTRL-C at the psql 
> prompt) without undoing its progress?

No.  You can safely interrupt it, but you won't have accomplished
anything if you do.

            regards, tom lane
```

Comment: ... and Tom is pretty much always right.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: OK. No problem. I'll keep that in mind for my next posts

Comment: Oh, it's worth noting that the mailing list post is from 2003, and in PostgreSQL 9.0 (?) the implementation of `VACUUM FULL` was *totally replaced* with a different one. So discussion of pre-9.0 vacuum full won't necessarily apply to post-9.0, though in this case it does.